# why can't the property of an object cached in redis be changed

Tags: redis

i save a item cached in redis , then i retrieve the item and change it property.

but the property can be changed , i have the code as the following : 
 the Item class:

```
public class QuoteBillItem{
private String netrate;

public String getNetrate() {        
    return netrate;     
}

public void setNetrate(String netrate) {
    this.netrate = netrate;
}

}


@Repository
public class RedisRepository {

@Autowired
private RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate;

private HashOperations<String, String, Object> itemHash;

public void saveItem(String hashKey, Object quoteBillItem) {
    itemHash.put("category", hashKey, qb);        
}

public void updateItem(QuoteBillItem qb, String newNr){
   qb.setNetrate(newNr);
}

public QuoteBillItem getFromMap(String hashKey){
    return (QuoteBillItem)itemHash.get("category", hashKey);
}
}


QuoteBillItem qb = new QuoteBillItem();
qb.setNetrate("1");
RedisRepository.saveItem("qb:key1",qb);
RedisRepository.updateItem(qb, "2");

QuoteBillItem qbcached = RedisRepository.getFromMap("qb:key1");

String  nr = qbcached.getNetrate();
```

the nr now still is 1 ,not 2 .

why can't the property of an object  cached in redis be modify?